# Recursion to find all level of child

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables. [Fiddle Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=819dbc7ff673a767ad233be1e22af51d)

`Details`

```
+-----+-----------+
| id  | valid     |
+-----+-----------+
| 101 | VALID     |
| 102 | NOT VALID |
| 103 | VALID     |
| 104 | NOT VALID |
+-----+-----------+
```

`Relation`

```
+---------+----------+-------+  
| parent  | child    | stock |
+---------+----------+-------+
| 101     | 101A     | 3     |
| 101     | 101B     | 1     |
| 101     | 101C     | 4     |
| 101A    | 101A-V1  | 3     |
| 101A-V1 | 101A-V2  | 6     |
| 102     | 102A     | 2     |
| 102     | 102B     | 3     |
| 103     | 103A     | 5     |
| 103     | 103BB    | 4     |
| 103     | 103M     | 5     |
| 103BB   | 103BB-V1 | 4     |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

I have to take id with "VALID" from `Details` and find all level of its children from `relation` table. So expected output is

```
+----------+-------+
| ID       | Valid |
+----------+-------+
| 101      | VALID |
| 101A     | VALID |
| 101B     | VALID |
| 101C     | VALID |
| 101A-V1  | VALID |
| 101A-V2  | VALID |
| 103      | VALID |
| 103A     | VALID |
| 103BB    | VALID |
| 103M     | VALID |
| 103BB-V1 | VALID |
+----------+-------+
```

I have tried the below cte but it is not giving its children. I'm getting only the top parent.

```
;with Cte2 As
        (
        SELECT a.*
        FROM details a
        WHERE a.valid = 'VALID'
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT a.*
        FROM details a
        join relation s 
        on a.id = s.child
        JOIN cte2 c ON s.parent = c.id
        )
        select * FROM Cte2
```

[**Fiddle Here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=819dbc7ff673a767ad233be1e22af51d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the child ID does not exist in the detail table, joining will not extract anything.

I think you should do it like this.

```
;with cte2 as
        (
        select 
            a.id,
            a.valid
        from details a
        where a.valid = 'VALID'
        union all
        select 
            s.child,
            c.valid
        from relation s 
        join cte2 c on s.parent = c.id
        )

select * from cte2 
order by cte2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is the best way to do do it, but this works for me.

```
;with cte as
(
select * from details
where valid = 'valid'
union
select R.child, FIRST_VALUE(D.valid) OVER (ORDER BY D.valid ASC) AS Valid
from details D
cross apply relation R
Where valid = 'valid' and D.id = left(R.parent,3))
select * from cte
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually code only answer. It would be nice if you could add some explanation how it works and when it works.

Comment: +1 for the attempt. But this works only in the sample given. Actually CHILD ID is not always first 3 characters of Parent ID. Just for easy understanding i have prepared the sample data in that way. Thanks anyway!